# How Can I have one parent ENTITY and many types of child ENTITIES in JPA?

Tags: jpa, entity

I am trying to design my **ENTITY CLASSES** using **JPA annotations**.

What I am trying to do is as follows :

**A USER table with**

**id,
***email,
password,
activation_key,
active,
role*****

and many **TYPES OF USER table** with for eg.

**STUDENT_TABLE

USER_ID
FirstName
LastName
Company
Address
etc**

**MENTOR

USER_ID
FirstName
LastNAme
DOB
Department
etc**

When USER will register depending o their ROLE they will be sotred in two tables (USER,MENTOR/STUDENT)

When they will log in , the ManagedBean will look into the UESR table to verify the authentication.

I tired to use @OneToOne but It just works with two tables.

I would really appreciate if any1 can help!!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, what you want is an inheritance relationship:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = JOINED)
public abstract class User { ... }

@Entity
public class Student extends User { ... }

@Entity
public class Mentor extends User { ... }
```

The JOINED strategy tells JPA that the fields in the User class are stored in a table (USER), and that each subclass persists its own field in its own table (STUDENT and MENTOR), with a join column used to refer to the USER table ID.

Comment: Thats really great man, thank you very much. So the data I am going to have in USER table will be accessible from each subclass ?

Comment: Do I need to put @DiscriminatorColumn anywhere ? if where ? Thanks

Comment: I think this depends on your JPA implementation. Hibernate doesn't need any discriminator column. If your engine needs one, then the annotation must be put on the User class, as explained in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/DiscriminatorColumn.html)